# Backlinking Realm

Tags: swift2, realm, xcode7.2

Hi I'm playing around with Realm and I'm trying to get and output of:

```
Fido has 1 owners (["John"])
Rex has 2 owners (["Mary","Bob"])
```

Though I keep on getting this output:

```
Fido has 1 owners (["John"])
Rex has 1 owners (["Mary"])
Rex has 1 owners (["Bob"])
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// this in the app delegate
 try! realm.write {
            realm.create(Person.self, value: ["John", [["Fido", 1]]])
            realm.create(Person.self, value: ["Mary", [["Rex", 2]]])
            realm.create(Person.self, value: ["Bob", [["Rex", 2]]])
        }

        // Log all dogs and their owners using the "owners" inverse relationship
        let allDogs = realm.objects(Dog)
        for dog in allDogs {
            let ownerNames = dog.owners.map { $0.name }
            print("\(dog.name) has \(ownerNames.count) owners (\(ownerNames))")
        }


class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    var owners: [Person] {
        // Realm doesn't persist this property because it only has a getter defined
        // Define "owners" as the inverse relationship to Person.dogs
        return linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "dogs")
    }
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, you're creating a completely separate `Rex` copy, each time you're adding a new owner to the database, not re-using the same one.

It might be better to create the `Dog` objects separately, in advance, and then reference those objects directly when creating the `Person` objects.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I'll have to play around and figure out how to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries! Yeah, in this case, it should just be a matter of not creating the dogs inline along with the owner. Let me know if you have any more questions! If not, feel free to mark this question as answered. ;)